# SQL IN query for approximate values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to retrieve information from a table using the SQL `IN` function.
I am using the following `select` and my logic is to search for fields containing the abbreviation 'SMS'. However, the query only retrieves values for 'Other Services'

How can I query for only a part of the value in the field?

This is the select function I am using:

```
select product_id ,product_name
from product 
where product_name 
IN ('Other Services','%SMS%')
```

I'm using PL/SQL Developer. For the time being I'm only interested in a solution that works for this DBMS.

Comment: Which DBMS? Do you need a solution working in all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT product_id,
       product_name
FROM   product
WHERE  product_name = 'Other Services'
   OR  product_name LIKE '%SMS%';
```

Beware that some database servers are case sensitive for the LIKE operator.

Comment: just in case you're not using a case insensitive collation > http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html this should do the trick ```...OR product_name COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%SMS%'```

Comment: You can also use: WHERE CHARINDEX('sms', product_name) > 0

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard charterers  "LIKE "can not be used in "IN" operator. The way you have used it.

to get the expected output you can use something like this.

SELECT product_id,
       product_name
FROM   product
WHERE  product_name = 'Other Services'
   OR  product_name LIKE '%SMS%'

OR

SELECT product_id,
       product_name
FROM   product
WHERE  product_name = 'Other Services'
   UNION

SELECT product_id,
       product_name
FROM   product
WHERE  product_name LIKE '%SMS%'

Comment: I take it that I can only use the exact values and full phrases in the "IN" operator?

Answer (score 0):

`IN` operator doesn't take values with wildcard characters. Instead use `LIKE` operator.

```
select product_id ,product_name
from product 
where product_name='Other Services' 
OR product_name LIKE '%SMS%'
```